# subscribe NAO laser head data

Tags: slam, localization, navigation, nao, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using NAO "Osiris", NAO with laser on the head. I want to get the laser data so I can use SLAM with gmapping, etc.

How to get the laser data ?

Thanks

Update : I already solved that. I decided to not use directly but from the NaoQi SDK. But as mentioned in the answer, it is very slow.

If someone need the code, I put it here :

Hello,

I am using NAO robot right now. And I need to get the laser data, but the current NAO stack doesn't provide that. The NAO that I use is NAO with laser head. The laser is Hokuyo URG-04LX.

I want to create node which publish LaserScan topic that I get from NaoQi SDK.
From the NaoQi, I can get this information :

- Min/Max Degree
- Min/Max Distance
- Array of Distance (size about : +/- 700)

Can I use that information to create the node that publish LaserScan topic ? If yes, can someone provide me the example of Hokuyo URG-04LX laser header, angle_increment, etc ?

If it is possible, I also want the example from the Hokuyo URG-04LX in the *.bag file.

Thank you :)

Update : thanks to the comment, I already can get the information via NaoQi SDK.

I put my code here, in case someone want to use it.

https://gist.github.com/rexcoder21/5957465

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65962/subscribe-nao-laser-head-data/) by [noob_coder](https://answers.ros.org/users/3154/noob_coder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You just start the [hokuyo_node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node) laser driver on the Nao and subscribe to the topic `scan`, that's all. For that to work you will have to crosscompile ROS (or at least the relevant parts including the hokuyo_node) for the Nao.

We also had some problems with the serial connection of the Nao's laser, so we connected the Hokuyo via USB instead.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noob_coder](https://answers.ros.org/users/3154/noob_coder/) on 2013-06-26**:
so I must install ROS inside the NAO ? can't I retrieve that from the computer ?

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-06-26**:
No, how else would you access the hardware that is attached to the robot? Unless you want to plug in the Hokuyo directly into the PC...

**Comment by [noob_coder](https://answers.ros.org/users/3154/noob_coder/) on 2013-06-26**:
Ok, I will try it ... thx for the your information

**Comment by [noob_coder](https://answers.ros.org/users/3154/noob_coder/) on 2013-07-02**:
@AHornung : do you know how to open the head, so I can access the hokuyo directly ? thx

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-07-02**:
@noob_coder: Well, there are screws ;)  Our head has a small opening where the USB port of the Hokuyo is to directly access it without opening the head.

**Comment by [noob_coder](https://answers.ros.org/users/3154/noob_coder/) on 2013-07-03**:
:( i didn't get permission to open the head :( ... they told me to get it without open the head ... can you help me ? can I create rostopic /scan from the data I got with python NaoQi SDK ? (i can retrieve with memory.getData("Device/Laser/Value") ? please guide me :(

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-07-03**:
Write a wrapper node similar to nao_sensors.py that puts the data in a scan message. We once had this, but it was awfully slow to get the data over NaoQI (3Hz vs 10Hz with the ROS Hokuyo driver).

**Comment by [noob_coder](https://answers.ros.org/users/3154/noob_coder/) on 2013-07-03**:
maybe I will try to get a shot, do you mind if I use your code ? can you send it to me or put it into https://gist.github.com/ ? I need that so bad :( thank you